# Citta experience during meditation

Tags: theravada

During meditation if no doer and knower operate citta come for knowing. Means thoughts coming with spaces without external object. Is this  what  do you call citta?  Is thoughts  are due to citta operate  without  self  ?when loba dvesa moha cease citta subjects to cease. Is it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Citta is the emotional mind-heart. When defilement of greed, hatred & delusion cease, the citta is pure, luminous & liberated (as explained in the [Pabhassara Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an01/an01.049.than.html)).

Comment: What do you mean by citta is the heart.

Comment: Where does  the emotional mind heart situated?Is it closer to real heart?

Comment: No. Citta is not the physical heart.